# Updating label on a HUD in Cocos2d iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

i am creating an HUD Layer on top of my Game Layer adding a label to display Score in that HUD with the help of following code

```
 // playGame Class

+(CCScene *) scene
{
// 'scene' is an autorelease object.
CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

// 'layer' is an autorelease object.
playGameLayer *layer = [playGameLayer node];

// add layer as a child to scene 
[scene addChild: layer];

// create HUD
    id statsHuds = [HUDlayer statsHUDWithBackgroundSprite:HUDBackground withRect:CGRectMake(160,30, 130,60)];

[statsHuds addLabeltoStatsHUDwithName:@"Score" andValue:@"50"];
//[statsHuds setStatusString:@"yewq"]; 
//[statsHuds updateScorewithValue:199];
// add HUD
    [scene addChild: statsHuds];

// return the scene


return scene;
}

- (id)init
{
    // always call "super" init
    // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super" return value
    if( (self=[super init])) 
    {

    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:NO];

    [self performSelector:@selector(updateLabel) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];

}
return self;
}

-(void)updateScore
{

HUDlayer *obj = [[HUDlayer alloc]init];
[obj setScoreString:@"100"];
[obj release];
}


// HUDLayer Class

+(id)statsHUDWithBackgroundSprite:(NSString *)spriteName withRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    HUDlayer *hud = [[HUDlayer alloc] init];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:spriteName];

CCSprite *statsSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:image.CGImage key:nil];
[statsSprite setPosition:ccp(rect.origin.x,rect.origin.y)];
[hud addChild:statsSprite];



return [hud autorelease];
}

-(void)addLabeltoStatsHUDwithName:(NSString *)labelName andValue:(NSString *)labelValue
{

[_statusLabel setString:@"no"];// [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"no" fntFile:@"Arial.fnt"];
[_statusLabel setPosition:ccp(160,240)];
[self addChild:_statusLabel];

}

// label added above is not updating
- (void)setScoreString:(NSString *)string 
{
    _statusLabel.string = string;

    NSLog(@"stats string after %@",_statusLabel.string);
}
```

_statuslbel is not updating once it gets added to the HUD even though NSlog returns the new value
what am i possibly doing wrong??

Comment: Where is _statusLabel created? And what is the updateScore method supposed to do? It seems to be creating a new layer every call.

Comment: in the init of HUDLayer class.. updateScore updates the score and needs to update the _statusLabel

Comment: Is the updateScore method supposed to be called frequenty? I also can't find the updateLabel method unless it's not included here.

Comment: it is present in init method of playgame class.. it is only called once after 5 seconds

Comment: This line: HUDlayer *obj = [[HUDlayer alloc]init]; 
And this line: HUDlayer *hud = [[HUDlayer alloc] init]; 

Are creating 2 seperate HUD layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your updateScore method, you are creating a new HUDLayer object each time this method is fired.

Instead, you need to reference the HUDLayer that you added to the scene. I suggest that you give your HUDLayer a tag:

```
[scene addChild: statsHuds z:0 tag:HUDTag];
```

Then in your updateScore method, access that HudLayer by its tag and update your score:

```
-(void)updateScore
{
    HUDLayer * obj = (HudLayer *)[self.parent getChildByTag:HUDTag];
    [obj setScoreString:@"100"];
}
```

Hope this helps.